# c# with Bitbucket.org error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#, cloud, bitbucket

We use Atlassian.Stash - C# API wrapper for Atlassian Stash, version v4.0.30319

C# .Net 4.8, Windows 10/1909

We migrated from Bitbucket Server to Bitbucket.org, and have the error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0`

```
try
{
  var client = new StashClient(ConfigParametres.GitBaseURL, username, 
  password);
  ResponseWrapper<Atlassian.Stash.Entities.Commit> allCommits = await 
  client.Commits.Get("PROJECT_KEY", "REPOSITORY_NAME", null, null);
  if (allCommits.Values == null)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact issue, but it sounds like the client is expecting JSON but getting HTML or XML from the server (maybe a login page? or error response?). I'd suggest using a tool like Telerik's Fiddler Classic to intercept the request/response and check what the response is.

Comment: In the Fiddler, how to understand what request/response is what? Should it be from process of VisualStudio?

Comment: You should be able to identify the URL that is being requested, then you can use the inspectors to view the request/response in its raw form.

Comment: In the Fiddler, I cannot see any URL with bitbucket.org.
I switched on https

Comment: switched to

https://github.com/lvermeulen/Bitbucket.Cloud.Net

But there is an error when calling GetRepositoryCommitsAsync()

Source "Flurl.Http"

Message "Response could not be deserialized to JSON: GET https://bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/bxbts/smscore/commits"

InnerException

Source "Newtonsoft.Json"

StackTrace

at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
...
at Flurl.Http.HttpResponseMessageExtensions.<ReceiveJson>d__0`1.MoveNext()

Message "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Comment: It's the same error. You need to find out what the actual response from the server is.

Comment: you should login with App Password. Go to bitbucket.org account > personal settings > App password. create app password and login with that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same issue by removing # and $ symbols from my password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Source tree for clone or any other application.
Then to overcome this issue you have 2 options:

1- disable two-step verification (not recommended).

2- create an app password and use this password to login in source tree.

Steps to create an app password:

1-  go to bitbucket, click on your avatar

2- choose personal settings

3- go to app passwords. choose create app password.

4- choose the permission associate with this password.

5- copy the generated password and use it to login in source tree (please take care that the password will be shown only in this step and you can't get it again).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have similar  error: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: L.Path '',line 0, position 0`

In my case I solved by change name from John Liu to john.

I guess Bitbucket goes error when you have blank or some special character in your username or password or some account information.

[image]

[image]